# best programming language for I/O intensive tasks

Tags: sed, perl, java, io, c++

I need to process "big data" (nearly 1TB which can be partitioned into smaller chunks). Consider several programming languages (Java, Python, C++, Perl) and other scripting options (Perl, awk, sed, etc.), how do/would they compare in performance in the following cases:

1. The data are in files, I just need to read them in and process them.
2. The data are in Oracle server, I need to fetch them from Oracle, process and then put them back to Oracle.

The language's syntactical complexity (i.e. how hard it is to learn or program) is not really important for my tasks. The main question is whether one is better than another at doing I/Os.

Comment: Shouldn't this go to StackOverflow?

Comment: unrelated: 1TB is not "big data".

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - no this Q is not really appropriate for SE sites. Too broad and primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

What you're proposing sounds like a lot of data but by today's standards is hardly anything that demanding. I deal with several times that regularly at work and any distro can deal with it, and any of the languages you've listed is fine for the task.

The limiting factor will be your physical HDD technologies. Everything else in the equation is a "DON'T CARE".

Comment: Also your higher level implementation is far more important than the language you choose. Anybody can write poor data processing logic in any language; first think about what you want to do and how you plan to do it, then use the best tool for the job based on what you know and what language expresses what you want to do as cleanly as possible. In any case the underlying software component of the IO will not be your bottleneck (all of the languages you cited use the same underlying IO mechanisms anyways, and all are mature and optimized for performance appropriately).